# Space between radio button and label different for different elements

Tags: html, radio-button, label, spacing

I can't figure out why the spacing between the radio input and link is different for the first element than for the other two.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="citationChoice">    
    <label for="mla">
        <input type="radio" name="citation" value="mla" id="mla_button" checked="checked">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="mla_text">MLA</a>
    </label> 

    <label for="apa">
        <input type="radio" name="citation" value="apa" id="apa_button"> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="apa_text">APA</a>
    </label> 

    <label for="chicago">
        <input type="radio" name="citation" value="chicago" id="chicago_button"> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="chicago_text">Chicago Manual of Style</a>
    </label> 
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kYF93/)

For some reason, without any css applied, the mla radio button is closer to the MLA link than the other radio buttons are to their adjacent links.

(I know the HTML is not completely correct. If at all possible, I have to leave the HTML as is.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a space before `<a` and jsfiddle was interpreting that. The first MLA link did not have this space, that is why it sat closer to the radio button

BEFORE -

```
id="apa_button"> <a
```

AFTER FIX -

```
id="apa_button"><a
```